# AchartEngine Bar Chart being drawn on the Y-Axis labels

Tags: android, achartengine

Good day, i have a slight issue here. How do i offset the x labels from the origin so that a graph can be plot correctly because when i try to plot a bar graph with custom X-labels, it plots from the origin of the X-labels and y-label coordinates and thus means it plots on the Y-Axis Labels as well. Anyway to shift the bar chart to plot values on the right of the X-labels or offset the x-labels by 1. Here is an Image. The bar chat is plotting on the Y-Axis Label.

[image: Bar Chart]

Any idea, how i can resolve this? like shifting it to the right or something? Thank you

Comment: True. The same issue exists in Vertical Bar graph and Horizontal as well. What did you do to fix it?

Comment: @manuelJ i am getting same issue?but accepted answer not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This used to be a bug in one of the releases. You can download a version including a fix for this [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/).

Comment: Thanks for the response. is it possible for you to tell me where the problem is, cos as i have slightly modified the code for the AchartEngine to fit my needs and can't change jar at this moment. Thanks for the consideration

Comment: Hard to tell as I don't remember.

Comment: ok thanks anyway. Will have to do that manually then. Actually i added code for padding on the labels on the jar i am using ()so maybe this one already has that as i see it was modified recently.

Comment: tried the new version but its not working. Problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

start add your Custom labels from index =1

```
renderer.addXTextLabel(index, key);
```

and add this line

```
renderer.setXAxisMin(0.5);
```

this will give you some space between bar and left y axis line